# API on collection not available in protocol extension

Tags: arrays, swift

There is some [documented API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Swift/MutableCollection/move(fromOffsets:toOffset:)) in Swift for moving items in an array.

The following extension does not compile.

> Value of type `[String]` has no member `move`.

```
protocol Database: AnyObject {
    var records: [String] { get set }
}

extension Database {
    
    func move(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) throws {
        records.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
//        try save()
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What is your environment?

Comment: iOS 13, Xcode 13.3 @RajaKishan

Comment: I tested it in the same environment it works fine.

Comment: That's strange. It doesn't work for me @RajaKishan have added photo evidence to OP. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please try with the fresh project?

Comment: It works in a fresh project... @RajaKishan

Comment: Found the answer @RajaKishan 

Comment: It's an extension on Collection declared in the SwiftUI module. Just import SwiftUI.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation states that this API is part of the standard library, yet it isn't available if you import Swift (or Foundation or UIKit).

This API is available in SwiftUI!

Comment: Almost everything on the web page you pointed to disagrees with what you see if you look at the documentation within Xcode itself. If you think you've found a bug in the documentation, please file a bug with Apple.